# While producing and consuming JSON in Java REST Services with Jersey getting exception

Tags: java, json, rest, service, jersey

```
  public class Message {
            private long id;
            private String message;
            private Date created;
            private String author;

            public Message(long id, String message, String author) {    
                this.id = id;
                this.message = message;
                this.author = author;
                this.created = new Date();
            }
            public long getId(

) {
```

Message is Model Class.....
  This is Post Methord:-

```
@POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)       
    public Message addMessage(Message msg){
        return mssageService.addMessage(msg);
    }
```

Above Method is use for Produces and  Consumes the JSON

This is Output:-

```
<h1>HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error</h1>
        <hr/>
        <p>
            <b>type</b> Exception report
        </p>
        <p>
            <b>message</b>Internal Server Error
        </p>
        <p>
            <b>description</b>The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
        </p>
        <p>
            <b>exception</b>
            <pre>javax.servlet.ServletException: org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.XMLUnmarshaller.setNamespaceResolver&#40;Lorg/eclipse/persistence/oxm/NamespaceResolver&#59;&#41;V</pre>
        </p>
        <p>
            <b>root cause</b>
            <pre>org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.XMLUnmarshaller.setNamespaceResolver&#40;Lorg/eclipse/persistence/oxm/NamespaceResolver&#59;&#41;V</pre>
        </p>
        <p>
            <b>root cause</b>
            <pre>java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.XMLUnmarshaller.setNamespaceResolver&#40;Lorg/eclipse/persistence/oxm/NamespaceResolver&#59;&#41;V</pre>
        </p>
        <p>
            <b>note</b>
            <u>The full stack traces of the exception and its root causes are available in the GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.1.1  logs.</u>
        </p>
        <hr/>
        <h3>GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.1.1 </h3>
    </body>
```

Here is the exception code with 
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.XMLUnmarshaller.setNamespaceResolver
exception

Comment: Post your jars/dependencies

Comment: Have you set the Mime type as "application/json" in the "Accept" header of the HTTP request?

Comment: which eclipse link version do you have?

Answer (score 0):

probably, you use a old version of eclipselink.

What i see from this site: http://grepcode.com/project/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.eclipse.persistence/eclipselink/

So my conclusion is to downgrade your eclipselink lib version.

Comment: try to check that the import jar are the correct version

Answer (score 0):

[setNamespaceResolver](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.eclipse.persistence/eclipselink/2.6.1-RC1/org/eclipse/persistence/internal/oxm/XMLUnmarshaller.java#XMLUnmarshaller.setNamespaceResolver%28org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.NamespaceResolver%29) exists only since eclipse link v 2.4 so upgrade it to v2.4 or greater